How to implement a custom pagination component in React?
I'm working on a React application where I need to implement a custom pagination component. The pagination should display up to 5 page links at a time, always include the first and last page links, and handle cases where there are fewer than 5 pages or when the current page is near the start or end of the pagination.
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Pagination = ({ total, current, onPageChange }) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(current);

  const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
    onPageChange(page);
  };

  const renderPageNumbers = () => {
    // Need help with the logic here
  };

  return (
    <div className="pagination">
      <button
        onClick={() => handlePageChange(1)}
        disabled={currentPage === 1}
      >
        First
      </button>
      {renderPageNumbers()}
      <button
        onClick={() => handlePageChange(total)}
        disabled={currentPage === total}
      >
        Last
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pagination;

I expect the renderPageNumbers function to generate up to 5 page links dynamically based on the current page and total pages, ensuring the first and last page links are always visible. For example, if I have 10 pages and I'm on page 6, it should display links like 1 ... 4 5 6 7 8 ... 10.
Currently, I'm unsure how to dynamically generate and display these page links in the renderPageNumbers function. The pagination doesn't adjust properly when the current page changes, and I'm struggling with the logic to handle different edge cases effectively.
So my question is how can I implement the renderPageNumbers function to achieve the described pagination behavior in React? Any advice or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

do you want the functionality for 1 ... 4 5 6 7 8 ... 10. these numbers or its just and text

To get the text representation of your pages you could use this logic:

function getPageArray(currentPage,highestNumber,range=5){
    const diff = Math.max(0,Math.floor(range/2))
    if(diff <= 0) throw new Error()
    if(highestNumber <=0) return [];
    if (highestNumber <=range) return Array.from({length: highestNumber}, (_, i) => ""+(i + 1));
    const final = ["1"]
    if (currentPage <= diff+1) {
        for (let i=2;i<=currentPage+diff;i++)final.push(""+i);
        final.push(...["...",""+highestNumber]);
        return final;
    }else if(currentPage >= highestNumber - diff){
        final.push("...");
        for(let i=currentPage-diff;i<=currentPage+diff;i++) {
            if(i>=highestNumber)break;
            final.push(""+i);
        }
        final.push(""+highestNumber)
        return final;
    }else{
        final.push("...");
        let i;
        for(i=currentPage-diff;i<=currentPage+diff;i++) {
            if(i>=highestNumber)break;
            final.push(""+i);
        }
        if (i < highestNumber)final.push("...");
        final.push(""+highestNumber);
        return final
    }
}


Basically it creates a text array of your values e.g. something like this:

getPageArray(1,10,5) //[ '1', '2', '3', '...', '10' ]
getPageArray(2,10,5) //[ '1', '2', '3', '4', '...', '10' ]
getPageArray(6,10,5) //[ '1', '...', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '...', '10']
getPageArray(10,10,5) //[ '1', '...', '8', '9', '10' ]


To then create link elements from it i would wrap it in a memo like this:
const pageButtons = useMemo(()=>{
    if(currentPage<0 || currentPage == undefined) return null;
    const baseArray = getPageArray(currentPage,10);
    return baseArray.map((page,index)=>{
        if(page === "...") return <span>...</span>
        const parsedInt = parseInt(page);
        return <button disabled={currentPage === parsedInt} onClick={()=>handlePageChange(parsedInt)}>{page}</button>
    })
},[currentPage])


then for the component return you can render the memoed results directly:

return (
    <div className="pagination">
      {pageButtons}
    </div>
  );

Note that i didn't use Last & first since they are just "texts". To change that i would change the map function in memo to display not the page but something else via a condition or predefined text or alternatively change the getPageArray function to return the right text. However then the parseInt might need some change :)
